# Strategy for reaching Wave 30 on Modern Warfare 3's survival map 'Resistance'?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I've been trying to survive Modern Warfare 3's survival map 'Resistance', but I cant get past Wave 25. I'm trying to survive until wave 30 but I'm not having any luck.

What is the best way for me to achieve this? I've used every tactic I know but none work.

Comment: It might be worth listing the tactics you've tried.

Comment: If you can list the tactics you have tried, we can help you much more. From what you have said, all we know is that you have gotten to wave 25, nothing else.

Comment: What have you tried *exactly*? Walling off? Sentries? Which weapons do you use? Do you lay down countermeasures? We can't help unless you help us understand where you're getting stuck...

Comment: i am hiding in the big building when i got to waves over 20. nd the reason im stuck is because they have so much armour and my squad of riotshielders died. i didnt have enough money for anything

Answer (score 2):

*I'd ask this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation*

1. What weapons are you using? - I prefer 2 lmg's (if you're level 50)
2. What perks are you using?

   - At later levels, the self-revive is pretty much useless, because the enemies have so much armor, there's no way you can kill them with a pistol (before getting killed).
   - The reason why I prefer 2 lmg's if you're level 50, is because that's when you get **Sleight Of Hand in survival**. That's really op with 2 lmg's.
   - The other perk is your personal choice, you can take the self-revive (it's still good if playing with a friend because of the extra time you get) if you want, but i prefer **Steady Aim** or **Quickdraw**.
3. Where does all your money go?

   - If you follow  these instructions, you should have a decent amount of money at round 24, 2 lmg's are worth of 14 000 + attachments (I prefer red dot sight and grip).
   - Riot shield group is good IF you know how to use them properly, they can't stand outside of the house, the helicopters will shoot them down. So don't waste your money on that every time they get killed unless you have a sentry gun (that doesen't shoot in a position the riot shield guys are).
4. What level are you?

   - Like I said before, you need **Sleight Of Hand**. It's just that great.

Now, if you are level 50, you have 2 light machine guns (**MG36** or **MK46** and **L86 LSW** are my favourites), **Sleight Of Hand**, some claymores in your pocket (and air strike/predator missile, i prefer air strike because you can just throw it out of the door on your left and everyone camping there dies/takes damage and you don't risk yourself by controlling the predator missile, which probably won't hit the target if it's middle round since there's enemies shooting at you) what you need to do, is just go in the house at the middle and just camp behind the sofa. (Or behind the table, requires more skill but it's better if you believe you can handle the people coming from the door on your left).

Put the claymores outside the door and the usual cover spots the enemies use inside the house.

When you run out of ammo, switch your weapon. There's no reason to reload if you have another lmg with full ammo. When you run out of ammo in that gun, then reload. And remember, you have **Sleight Of Hand**.

**IMO** This is probably the best strategy there is, if you still can't do it, just practice more and try again.

Oh, almost forgot: You'll also need flashbangs. Not to blind the enemy so you can shoot them without getting shot, you should find a cover to do that. But so you can run pass them if you need some ammo/armor.

Hopefully this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

One of the best strategies of more armored enemies is buying a couple of c4 ...hide in the center building then plant some c4 around the courtyard ...they usually bundle up in that area and once they do BANG took out 50% then predator missle the juggs

Answer (score -1):

Hide in the kitchen and and have your turrets by the fire place. But watch for the turrets sometimes can hurt you if an enemy gets to close. But for jugs yes the predator missile does help but I have gotten to wave 30 no problem with out using that. Just flash the hell out of them and the enemy's but don't stay in the house when you got 3 or more jugs plus men and dogs run lol. Lay down c4 and flash em and blow them up! I been doing that since the first day I never have a problem getting past 30 but everyone has their own way. I favor the light heavy guns they help a lot with the grip and steady aim

Answer (score -2):

Grab a couple friends, and camp inside the center building. When Juggernauts spawn, buy predator missiles from the nearby shop and take them out. You have to be kinda good at the game to do it right though.

Comment: its only 2 player on survival. its just the enemies have soo much armour i have no idea what to do about THAT

Answer (score -2):

Honestly I use two grenade turrets two light heave machine gun. Many c4s and mines also I hide in the house until the jugs come out to play. Then I flash the hell out of them and unload my heavys on them ! I made it to wave 34 but not past it.